# pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive error in PostgreSQL using Pgadmin 4 in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: django, postgresql, pg-restore

I'm trying to restore sql file backup of database in postgresql. It gives me above error.

I have done following operations.

```
psql test </opt/backup.sql
```

and

```
pg_restore -U postgres -d test </opt/backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

you backup gone wrong.

try to create a new one . with valid user and database

Comment: When I open the sql file in Mysql Workbench, its working.

Comment: postgresql backup file extension should be .pgsql extention . like backup.pgsql , not backup.sql

Comment: if you are try any other database backup. it would not work with simple export command

Comment: But in windows , I run pg_dump.exe -U postgres BPS_Server >"d:\backup.sql"   command in  command prompt ,it works.

Comment: try to import it with pg admin

Comment: I tried but couldn't do.Can I ask another django related question?

Comment: sure .sure .sure .sure .sure .